# other ways to write regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

Are there other ways you can write this regular expression?

for

```
var pattern = /^(1[-\.\s])?([{]?\d{3})?[)]?\)?[-. ]?(\d{3})[-. ]?(\d{3})[-. ]?(\d{4})$/;
```

```js
"use strict";
var $ = function(id) { return document.getElementById(id); };

var validatePhone = function() {
    var phone = $("phone").value;
    //var pattern = /^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$/; 
    
    var pattern = /^(1[-\.\s])?([{]?\d{3})?[)]?\)?[-. ]?(\d{3})[-. ]?(\d{3})[-. ]?(\d{4})$/;
    
    // 1-999-999-9999

    var isValid = pattern.test(phone);

    
    $("message").firstChild.nodeValue = (isValid) ? "Valid phone number" : "Invalid phone number";
};

window.onload = function() {
    $("validate").onclick = validatePhone;
    $("phone").value = "";  // set default phone number
};
```

I know this validates the phone number lets say **1-111-111-1111**,

but are there any other ways to recreate this code to make it have the same features?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain clearly what you are trying to achieve. If the aim is to validate a phone number, please explain what format(s) you want to allow. *"I know this outputs the phone number"* - It doesn't really *output* anything. It could be used to *validate* whether a given input string conforms to that pattern. Note that the expression shown allows spaces and full stops too, but you haven't said whether that is what you want.

Comment: What should be exactly the pattern because this I think accepts **1-999-999-9999** when I put 9 accept this as a digit. So is this the pattern you want to match?

Comment: @ sand yea those kinds of numbers

Comment: @nnnnnn ah you're right/ I was wanting the option of having a 1 the option of having dashes or periods and also have optional parenthesis.

Comment: @temurb: As sand wrote: Could you provide some valid numbers as well as some invalid examples?